# Libgdx music/sound effect with reverb

Tags: audio, libgdx

Is it possible to add specific reverb to my sound effect/music track in libgdx?
I want to add outdoor/indoor reverb to make all tracks sounded the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that Libgdx has a mechanism to adding effects to sound. The [Sound](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/audio/Sound.html) class delivers no function for this.

I see three solutions here:

- **Prepare two kinds of sounds** (one with reverb one without - it is easy to do using software like [Audacity](http://audacityteam.org/) - and play one or another due to environment of player's current being
- **Try to implement it yourself**

  I see that in the Sound class there is `setPitch(long soundId, float pitch)` method. Due to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverberation) the reverb is just a kind of echo so maybe (but not for sure) you could achieve the effect by

  1. making copy of sound
  2. slowering it a little
  3. lowering the volume
  4. playing simultaneously with original sound
- **Find 3rd part library that will do it for you** - the Google returns some examples of libs working with libgdx like [SoundTouch Audio Processing Library](http://www.surina.net/soundtouch/) - maybe you will find something usefull

First one is the easiest and if you are not afraid of space problems I would strongly recommend it to you (althought why not to try implementing it)

Comment: If you know Pure data, there is a recent libGDX extension here : https://github.com/mgsx-dev/gdx-pd

Answer (score 0):

[I've implemented](https://stormcloak.games/2022/06/06/spatial-sounds) reverb, positional audio, and arbitrary filters using OpenAL against the latest libgdx 1.10+/lwjgl 3+ with [this demo code](https://github.com/soundasleep/libgdx-openal-reverb-demo), based off of [gdx-sfx](https://github.com/spookygames/gdx-sfx) (which only works with lwjgl 2) and [libgdx-audio-effects](https://github.com/abvadabra/libgdx-audio-effects).

I'd like to promote this into a fully fledged library at some point